# Having trouble with scipy.interpolation.interpn

Tags: python, scipy

I'm having trouble understanding the input format of the parameters in the function interpn. The example that is given in the documentation is really confusing me

Here is the example they gave:

```
import numpy as np  
from scipy.interpolate import interpn  
def value_func_3d(x, y, z):
        return 2 * x + 3 * y - z
x = np.linspace(0, 4, 5)
y = np.linspace(0, 5, 6)
z = np.linspace(0, 6, 7)
points = (x, y, z)
values = value_func_3d(*np.meshgrid(*points, indexing='ij'))
point = np.array([2.21, 3.12, 1.15])
print(interpn(points, values, point))
```

Below is what points and values looks like

```
print(points)

(array([0., 1., 2., 3., 4.]), array([0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5.]), array([0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6.]))

print(values)

[[[ 0. -1. -2. -3. -4. -5. -6.]
  [ 3.  2.  1.  0. -1. -2. -3.]
  [ 6.  5.  4.  3.  2.  1.  0.]
  [ 9.  8.  7.  6.  5.  4.  3.]
  [12. 11. 10.  9.  8.  7.  6.]
  [15. 14. 13. 12. 11. 10.  9.]]

 [[ 2.  1.  0. -1. -2. -3. -4.]
  [ 5.  4.  3.  2.  1.  0. -1.]
  [ 8.  7.  6.  5.  4.  3.  2.]
  [11. 10.  9.  8.  7.  6.  5.]
  [14. 13. 12. 11. 10.  9.  8.]
  [17. 16. 15. 14. 13. 12. 11.]]

 [[ 4.  3.  2.  1.  0. -1. -2.]
  [ 7.  6.  5.  4.  3.  2.  1.]
  [10.  9.  8.  7.  6.  5.  4.]
  [13. 12. 11. 10.  9.  8.  7.]
  [16. 15. 14. 13. 12. 11. 10.]
  [19. 18. 17. 16. 15. 14. 13.]]

 [[ 6.  5.  4.  3.  2.  1.  0.]
  [ 9.  8.  7.  6.  5.  4.  3.]
  [12. 11. 10.  9.  8.  7.  6.]
  [15. 14. 13. 12. 11. 10.  9.]
  [18. 17. 16. 15. 14. 13. 12.]
  [21. 20. 19. 18. 17. 16. 15.]]

 [[ 8.  7.  6.  5.  4.  3.  2.]
  [11. 10.  9.  8.  7.  6.  5.]
  [14. 13. 12. 11. 10.  9.  8.]
  [17. 16. 15. 14. 13. 12. 11.]
  [20. 19. 18. 17. 16. 15. 14.]
  [23. 22. 21. 20. 19. 18. 17.]]]
```

I tried the following and it didn't work.

```
test_coords = coords.iloc[0:3,:].to_numpy()
test_density = density.iloc[0:3].to_numpy()
interpn(test_coords, test_density, (1,1,1))
```

Here is what test_coords and test_density look like:

```
print(test_coords)
[[  0.4   0.4 -15.6]
 [  1.2   0.4 -15.6]
 [  2.    0.4 -15.6]]
print(test_density)
[7.17427017e-08 6.80979370e-08 6.13095000e-08]
```

Here is the error message I get when trying to run `interpn(test_coords, test_density, (1,1,1))`

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-79d0b96dca9c> in <cell line: 16>()
     14 print(test_coords)
     15 print(test_density)
---> 16 interpn(test_coords, test_density, (1,1,1))
     17 
     18 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/scipy/interpolate/_rgi.py in interpn(points, values, xi, method, bounds_error, fill_value)
    629     # sanity check consistency of input dimensions
    630     if len(points) > ndim:
--> 631         raise ValueError("There are %d point arrays, but values has %d "
    632                          "dimensions" % (len(points), ndim))
    633     if len(points) != ndim and method == 'splinef2d':

ValueError: There are 3 point arrays, but values has 1 dimensions
```

Comment: What are `test_coords`? You didn't define that variable.

Comment: Also, you say it "didn't work". What didn't work?

Comment: @jared test_coords is a numpy array containing the values shown in the image

Comment: Include those array definitions as text in your post. Don't share images of code.

Comment: @jared I'll fix it now

Comment: You also shouldn't share images of errors. Copy the error message and include it in your post.

Comment: We don't have `coords` to be able to create `test_coords` or `test_density`. Please read about [minimal reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

`scipy.interpolate.interpn` performs data interpolation on a rectilinear grid. To do so, the function call requires the user to provide the coordinates of the grid points, the values of a given field at these grid points, and the coordinates of the points at which interpolated values should be returned.

In the example from the documentation, the coordinates of the grid points are given as a tuple of three 1-D NumPy arrays. Each NumPy array contains the coordinates of grid vertices along an individual axis in space. This is sufficient to deduce the coordinates of all grid points, given the assumed structure of the grid. The values of the field to interpolate are provided as a 3-D NumPy array. The shape of this array is necessarily the combination in the same order of the size of each 1-D NumPy array given as coordinates. Finally, the coordinates of the points at which an interpolated value is requested should be a 2-D NumPy array: the first dimension corresponds to the number of points where interpolation should be performed, whilst the second dimension represents the number of space axes.

There are multiple problems in your attempt to use `interpn`. It seems to me that you are providing the full coordinates of individual points instead of providing the coordinates of the grid on each axis. Those coordinates have to be strictly increasing or decreasing. Assuming the latter is correct, you are providing values at these three points, which is consistent, but keep in mind you will have to provide values for all grid points as a 3-D NumPy array (given your space seems to be 3-D).

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code doesn't work is because your `test_coords` are each of length 3 while your `test_density` is only of length 3. If you print out `values.shape` from the scipy example, you'll see that the shape is `(5, 6, 7)`, which matches the lengths of each of the coordinates (`x` is length 5, `y` is length 6, and `z` is length 7). So, your `test_density`, based on the coordinates you show, should be of shape `(3,3,3)`.

Comment: My understanding of what 'values' should be is the values corresponding to the points in 'points'. So in my test_coords (which represents 'points') I have three points, that is why the shape is (3,3), and then in test_density (which represents 'values') the shape is (3,1) so that each element in test_density corresponds to one point in test_coords.

Comment: `values` should be the value at the `meshgrid` points.

Comment: I see, so in my case I don't believe I have the density values for the meshgrid points. I only have values for some large amount of points that don't necessarily correspond to a meshgrid (from my understanding of what a meshgrid is). Is there any alternative interpolation function that you can recommend that would work in my case? I can provide more context if necessary.

Comment: @AlejandroEspino You haven't really provided much information about your problem and goals. Based on what I've seen, you might be able to use [`scipy.interpolate.griddata`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html#scipy.interpolate.griddata) instead. See the bottom of the documentation page for an example.